# update_attributeの実行方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初心者です。ご助力お願いいたします。
update_attributeの実行方法がわかりません。
findを使ってupdate_attributeをしようとしたところ以下のエラーが出ました。

```
irb(main):034:0> @user = User.find(1)

irb(main):035:0> @user.update_attribute(name: "ABC")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):35
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))

irb(main):036:0> @user.update_attributes(name: "ABC")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

なぜupdate_attributesではエラーが出ずにupdate_attributeではエラーがでるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> なぜupdate_attributesではエラーが出ずにupdate_attributeではエラーがでるのでしょうか？

`update_attribute`の呼び出し方が間違っていることが原因です。
以下のように呼び出すと実行できると思います。

```
@user.update_attribute(:name, "ABC")
```

---

### update_attribute

`update_attribute`は1つの属性のみを更新・保存するメソッドになります。
以下のように、属性名とその値を指定し使用します。(参考: [update_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute))

```
# 引数が2つ
update_attribute(name, value)
```

そのため、以下で実行できると思います。

```
@user.update_attribute(:name, "ABC")
```

### update_attributes

一方、`update_attributes`は複数の属性をまとめて更新・保存するメソッドになります。
以下のように使用します。([参考: update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes))

```
# 引数がハッシュ
update_attributes(attributes)
```

引数の`attributes`部分にはハッシュを渡すことができます。
引数にハッシュを渡すことで複数の属性をまとめて更新・保存できます。

```
# 引数がハッシュ  {name: "ABC", age: 10}部分がハッシュ
@user.update_attributes({name: "ABC", age: 10})
# rubyでは、メソッドの末尾の引数のハッシュは`{, }`を省略できるので
# 以下も同じ意味になります。
@user.update_attributes(name: "ABC", age: 10)
```